# Why with WAMP utlizes computer name as wireless LAN access not working on Firefox or Safari but Chrome only?

Tags: domain, wireless-networking, localhost, wamp

I found that when use WAMP on win8, I able to access my wireless LAN like this:
if my computer name is `mypc`, I am able to see the WAMP loitself by type in `mypc` in the address bar for Chrome. But when I try to do the same in Safari or Firefox, they will display error message of :

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I wonder why this is trouble in those browsers while ok with Chrome?

Also is it possible to setup some kind of user name + passwords to access the localhost WAMP menu when use in a wireless LAN?

Thanks

Comment: Try specifying the port you are using .

Comment: Honestly, I did not really use any port...but maybe 808# something?

Comment: Are you using all 3 browsers from the same device or different devices?

Answer (score 0):

It kind of sounds like the other two Browsers might be sending a different `Host` Header, which would normally need to match the VirtualHost's `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`.

Use Chrome's Dev Tools (F12) to see the Request Headers being generated and sent, specifically the `Host: xxx` value. And then do the same under Firefox.

Then make sure your VirtualHost has that same value set as `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`.

If this is what is happening, then right now Apache is returning either the default VirtualHost, or the root server context, which might be set to `Deny All`.